# OpenGL 3.0, cannot draw textured quad

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to modify a sample from the OpenGL ES 3.0 programming guide book, but I cannot figure out why I can't draw a textured quad.

here is the main drawing loop (extracted from the book, with minor modifications):

```
void DrawTexturedQuad(ESContext *esContext)
{
    UserData *userData = static_cast<UserData *>(esContext->userData);
    GLfloat vVertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Position 0
        0.0f,  0.0f,        // TexCoord 0 
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Position 1
        0.0f,  1.0f,        // TexCoord 1
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Position 2
        1.0f,  1.0f,        // TexCoord 2
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Position 3
        1.0f,  0.0f         // TexCoord 3
    };
    GLushort indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };

    // Use the program object
    glUseProgram ( userData->programObjectMultiTexture );

    // Load the MVP matrix
    glUniformMatrix4fv(userData->mvpLoc, 1, GL_FALSE,(GLfloat *) &userData->grid.mvpMatrix.m[0][0]);

    #define LOCATION_VERT   (7)
    #define LOCATION_TEXT   (8)

    // Load the vertex position
    glVertexAttribPointer ( LOCATION_VERT, 3, GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof ( GLfloat ), vVertices );
    // Load the texture coordinate
    glVertexAttribPointer ( LOCATION_TEXT, 2, GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof ( GLfloat ), &vVertices[3] );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( LOCATION_VERT );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray ( LOCATION_TEXT );

    // Bind the base map
    glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, userData->baseMapTexId );

    // Set the base map sampler to texture unit to 0
    glUniform1i ( userData->baseMapLoc, 0 );

    // Bind the light map
    glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE1 );
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, userData->lightMapTexId );

    // Set the light map sampler to texture unit 1
    glUniform1i ( userData->lightMapLoc, 1 );

    glDrawElements ( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices );

    glDisableVertexAttribArray ( LOCATION_VERT );
    glDisableVertexAttribArray ( LOCATION_TEXT );
}
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

uniform                 mat4 u_mvpMatrix;
layout(location = 7) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 8) in vec2 a_texCoord;

out vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
   //gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.f);
   gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * vec4(a_position, 1.f);
   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

the Fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec2 v_texCoord;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;
uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;
uniform sampler2D s_lightMap;

void main()
{
    vec4 baseColor;
    vec4 lightColor;

    baseColor = texture( s_baseMap, v_texCoord );
    lightColor = texture( s_lightMap, v_texCoord );

    outColor = baseColor * (lightColor + 0.25);
    //outColor = vec4(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
}
```

I did three tests, but they all look incorrect although the setup and shaders look right to me.

1st test (top window of the picture). The code is as shown above.

2nd test (middle window of the picture). I by passed the samplers and hard-coded the color on the fragment shader like so:

```
outColor = vec4(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
```

This proved that my matrices are correct, since I see a white quad properly tranformed on the screen.

3rd test (bottom window). I bypassed the matrix tranform to test if the samplers are correct. I do see the textured quad rendered but no transformation. like so:

```
// this is so odd, I can see the textures!!!!
// why the transform can mess things up?
gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.f);
v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
```

Anyway, if anyone can spot the issue, I'd really appraciated. I am using the Mali ARM emulator and there is no way to debug the shader, I have no idea what is going on inside. Yet, the code setup looks correct but they don't seem to work all together for some reason.

[image]

Comment: In your code, there is no guarantee that `u_mvpMatrix` has location 1. You have to query the location or fix it in the shader.

Comment: Thanks BDL this fixed the issue